# ¿ Como ordenar un JSON por la fecha de un objeto?

Tags: javascript, json

Quisiera que el listado se ordene por el campo "createdAt" por la fecha mas reciente del objeto chat.

Intente acceder al campo con esta forma, pero no logro que se ordene, tengo la duda si es por el formato de fecha que esta recibiendo.

```js
let sortArray = chatSalaArray.sort((a,b) => a.chat.createdAt - b.chat.createdAt)
```

```js
chatSalaArray: [
  {
    id_user1: {
      perNom: 'Hernan, Rios Valencia',
      perCod: 626f14f66d157518bcb62c40,
    },
    id_user2: {
      perNom: 'Apheli, Fabilli Da Silva',
      perCod: 62096a989f4470104881266e,
    },
    unionfr: '626f14f66d157518bcb62c40-62096a989f4470104881266e',
    _id: 6345f3245860001cb00cf65c,
    chat: {
      createdAt: 2022-10-11T22:50:18.493Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-11T22:50:18.493Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id_user1: {
      perNom: 'Mery, Carrasco Ríos',
      perCod: 62203c063bc3c74128ba9516,
      perNomBus: 'MeryCarrascoRíos.YFM.0'
    },
    id_user2: {
      perNom: 'Apheli, Fabilli Da Silva',
      perCod: 62096a989f4470104881266e,
    },
    unionfr: '62203c063bc3c74128ba9516-62096a989f4470104881266e',
    _id: 6345f33e5860001cb00cf65e,
    chat: {
      createdAt: 2022-10-11T22:53:54.969Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-10-11T22:53:54.969Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: ¿Ese objeto te viene dado o lo creas tu?  Lo digo porque hay muchos campos sin comillas y son strings (perCod, _id, createdAt y updateAt)

Comment: Lo recibo desde MongoDB amigo

Comment: ¿has podido probar mi respuesta?  ¿te sirve o voy equivocado?  Me da apuro lo de las comillas, pero no se, nunca he trabajado con MongoDB y no se como va eso.

Comment: Hola, al parecer si es el tema de las comillas. En la respuesta con el ejemplo que colocaste con las fechas con comillas si funciona.

Comment: La fecha me llega sin comillas en ese formato createdAt: 2022-10-10T03:20:51.687Z, pero si lo transformo con .toString(), se convierte a otro formato Tue Oct 11 2022 17:53:54 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central)

Comment: ¿y no puedes ponerle las comillas de algun modo al recibirlo desde Mongodb?  (lo que dije antes lo he borrado porque no habia visto la coletilla final que decia eso de (hora de verano central) ). Si intento hacerlo sin las comillas me da error de javascript, por eso lo digo, no es un objeto válido, por eso me extraña que te lo devuelva así.

Comment: Claro, despues de obtener el BSON de MongoDB.  Lo envio al front con Angular y este lo recibe en formato JSON y todos los campos de los objetos vienen con comillas.  Por ejemplo. en el front recibo la fecha con comillas asi : createdAt
: 
"2022-10-11T22:50:18.493Z"

Comment: perfecto, pues ya lo tienes, no?  Lo haces en el front y andando

Comment: Así es, ya que tengo el JSON con comillas. ya puedo ordenarlo con el método que pasaste.  Hombre muchas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicacion para solucionar mi problema.  Saludos desde Perú amigo.

Comment: me alegro que te haya funcionado... si mi respuesta cumple cn tu pregunta recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que no quede pendiente para siempre y la comunidad lo sepa, gracias!  En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inténtalo así:

```
let sortArray = obj.chatSalaArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   date1 = new Date(a.chat.createdAt)
   date2 = new Date(b.chat.createdAt)
  return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()
})
```

Ejemplo:

```js
obj = {
  chatSalaArray: [{
      id_user1: {
        perNom: 'Hernan, Rios Valencia',
        perCod: '626f14f66d157518bcb62c40',
      },
      id_user2: {
        perNom: 'Apheli, Fabilli Da Silva',
        perCod: '62096a989f4470104881266e',
      },
      unionfr: '626f14f66d157518bcb62c40-62096a989f4470104881266e',
      _id: '6345f3245860001cb00cf65c',
      chat: {
        createdAt: '2022-11-11T22:50:18.493Z',
        updatedAt: '2022-11-11T22:50:18.493Z',
        __v: 0
      }
    },
    {
      id_user1: {
        perNom: 'Mery, Carrasco Ríos',
        perCod: '62203c063bc3c74128ba9516',
        perNomBus: 'MeryCarrascoRíos.YFM.0'
      },
      id_user2: {
        perNom: 'Apheli, Fabilli Da Silva',
        perCod: '62096a989f4470104881266e',
      },
      unionfr: '62203c063bc3c74128ba9516-62096a989f4470104881266e',
      _id: '6345f33e5860001cb00cf65e',
      chat: {
        createdAt: '2022-10-11T22:53:54.969Z',
        updatedAt: '2022-10-11T22:53:54.969Z',
        __v: 0
      }
    }
  ]
}

let sortArray = obj.chatSalaArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   date1 = new Date(a.chat.createdAt)
   date2 = new Date(b.chat.createdAt)
  return date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()
})
console.log(sortArray)
```

En el ejemplo he cambiado las fechas y he entrecomillado los campos `perCod, _id, createdAt y updateAt`.

Básicamente he convertido esas cadenas de fecha en objetos [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) y he usado su conversión a time con [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) para realizar la resta con números.